# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars arrives during a simple program

Tags: python, numpy

When I tried this code,

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np

w1=2
b1=0.5
b2=0.75

X=[[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
y=(np.dot(w1,X)-b1)
tanh=np.vectorize((1-exp(-2*y))/(1+exp(-2*y)))
y_out=1/(1+np.exp(-tanh))-b2 

print(y_out)
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars..

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `math.exp` requires scalar inputs.  `y` is an array. Also `np.vectorize` takes a function, not a number or array.  `np.exp(y)` should run.

Comment: in addition to what hpaulj said, just use `np.exp` which already works with arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [269]: import math                                                           
In [270]: w1=2 
     ...: b1=0.5 
     ...: b2=0.75 
     ...: X=[[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]] 
     ...: y=(np.dot(w1,X)-b1)                                                   
In [271]: X                                                                     
Out[271]: [[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
In [273]: y                                                                     
Out[273]: 
array([[-0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5],
       [ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5]])
```

Python evaluates the argument to `np.vectorize` before it calls `vectorize`.  It should be a function, but what you wrote was an expression.

The error arises in:

```
In [274]: math.exp(-2*y)                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-274-02e40bf10b29> in <module>
----> 1 math.exp(-2*y)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

`y` is an array; `math.exp` only works with scalar values.  `np.exp` works with arrays:

```
In [275]: np.exp(-2*y)                                                          
Out[275]: 
array([[2.71828183, 0.04978707, 0.04978707, 0.04978707],
       [0.04978707, 0.04978707, 0.04978707, 0.04978707]])
```

With a `lambda` `vectorize` works:

```
In [276]: fn = np.vectorize( lambda z: (1-math.exp(-2*z))/(1+math.exp(-2*z)))   
In [277]: fn(y)                                                                 
Out[277]: 
array([[-0.46211716,  0.90514825,  0.90514825,  0.90514825],
       [ 0.90514825,  0.90514825,  0.90514825,  0.90514825]])
```

`vectorize` iterates through `y`, and passes an element, one at a time, to the `lambda` as `z`.

but this is faster:

```
In [278]: (1-np.exp(-2*y))/(1+np.exp(-2*y))                                     
Out[278]: 
array([[-0.46211716,  0.90514825,  0.90514825,  0.90514825],
       [ 0.90514825,  0.90514825,  0.90514825,  0.90514825]])
```

---

The `vectorize` is essentially a variation on this list comprehension:

```
In [280]: [ (1-math.exp(-2*z))/(1+math.exp(-2*z)) for z in y.ravel()]           
Out[280]: 
[-0.46211715726000974,
 0.9051482536448665,
 0.9051482536448665,
 0.9051482536448665,
 0.9051482536448665,
 0.9051482536448665,
 0.9051482536448665,
 0.9051482536448665]
```